# Improving MySQL response time with complex query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok I made this long query. It works perfect but it takes 15-30 seconds to give me the results... I'm not an SQL expert so I want to ask if there is a way to improve the MySQL response time... maybe doing it in more than 1 query or something like that.

PS: Its a BIG database that contains all the financial information of a big company.

PS2: I'm connecting to MySQL with PHP.

```
SELECT
    aplicaciones.importe, facturas.cliente, facturas.porcenRUC, 
    facturas.porcenTB, facturas.codcmp, facturas.prefijo, facturas.numero,
    clientes.vendedor, comisiones.ruc, comisiones.trb, recibos.prefijo as prefijoR,
    recibos.numero as numeroR
FROM recibos, aplicaciones, facturas, clientes, comisiones
WHERE 
    (recibos.fechaAcrMax BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$dd', '%d/%m/%Y') AND 
    STR_TO_DATE('$hh', '%d/%m/%Y')) AND recibos.base = aplicaciones.base AND 
    recibos.identificador = aplicaciones.identificador AND 
    recibos.base = facturas.base AND
    aplicaciones.aplica_a_identificador = facturas.identificador AND 
    facturas.cliente = comisiones.cliente AND
    facturas.cliente = clientes.cliente 
ORDER BY clientes.vendedor ASC
```

Comment: What kind of indexes do you have on those tables?  That helps with the speed of big queries.  Also, you should use join syntax, JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID

Comment: The query uses implicit inner joins... I don't have the table I just have a view of it, but i'm sure it has the proper indexes.

Comment: You want to check the indexes.  This isn't a super complicated query so most of the work is in the where clause and streaming the results back to your machine from the database.

Comment: Read the coment i left on the first answer. I couldn't check the indexes.

Comment: If you can't check the indexes how could you create new ones even if they are needed?

Comment: My boss isn't at the office, I will ask him for the pribilegies to set new indexes...

Answer (score 2):

First step would be to see if you can add indexes.  Run your query again but with 'EXPLAIN ' at the start and the results should help you identify what indexes are being used and what indexes you can or should add.

The documentation on the mysql website should help:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

Documentation on indexes is available here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: I tried to use EXPLAIN but: #1345 - EXPLAIN/SHOW can not be issued; lacking privileges for underlying table ||| It's because I just have a view of the real table...